# Is using a single global variable for angular modules an anti-pattern?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I found some a template, and in reviewing it, discovered that the var anApp is declared once in app.js, and is subsequently shared by all modules. My questions are: 1. Will using a single variable cause all angular components to get stored in the global scope? 2. Is this an anti-pattern, or an ok design pattern? If in the affirmative on either, can anyone suggest a best-practice approach?

Thank you

```
---app.js----
 var anApp = angular.module("myApp", [
    "ui.router", 
    "ui.bootstrap", 
    "oc.lazyLoad",  
    "ngSanitize"
]); 

anApp.config(['$ocLazyLoadProvider', function($ocLazyLoadProvider) {...}]);

---controllers.js---
anApp.controller('fooCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {...}]);

---directives.js---
anApp.directive('ngSpinnerBar', ['$rootScope',function($rootScope) {...}]);
```

etc.

Comment: Well bearing in mind that `angular` is itself a global variable...

Comment: You can always use angular module getter syntax inorder to avoid adding the global variable holding the module. i.e `angular.module("myApp").controller...`

Comment: @PSL, thanks. Is either pattern better design/practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For very small applications you can live with only one module. In this case you can follow many samples and use one global variable so you don't have to make a lookup for the module by name. And having only one additional global variable won't hurt so much, especially if it has a name which can be recognized as the "app" module by everyone reading your code.

But I'd say having only one module for a mid-size application (or even greater) is an anti-pattern. And creating a module for every artifact (e.g. a controller) is not only an anti-pattern, but big non-sense. Creating a module for each type of artifact ('myControllers', 'myDirectives', ...) doesn't make much sense but it maybe better than nothing.

You should identify and create your modules in a "natural" way.

- which artifacts belong together?
- what dependencies exist between artifacts and modules?
- would the dependency graph look like big spaghetti or more like a tree?
- are there small units which could as well live in another web application?
- do you have artifacts which could be shared as an open source module?
- can you split your application in vertical parts (e.g. login, user-admin, statistics, ...) and/or horizontal parts (access-layer/caching, logic/communication, ui)?

I think in a mid-sized application you typically come out with 10-30 modules. A small number (~10) could be reused in other projects, the rest are modules which are domain specific. Your number of modules may be totally different and still super-valid. It depends on the size of your app and the granularity you want to have in your modules. In my opinion having <30 modules might still be easy enough to have a view of them without being lost in the forrest.

To your other questions: As of Angular 1.3 it doesn't make any difference after loading the application how many modules you have. You have only one injector and all artifacts will be injected by their unique name (besides directives, where you can have more than one with the same name). Angular doesn't create new variables in the global scope, all artifacts are looked up in the "registry" (aka. injector).

Comment: thank you for a very clear explantation